# Package similar to upref for hyperrefs

Tags: fonts, hyperref, cross-referencing

I have been using `upref` to remove italics in `\ref`s. Does there exist a package that does the same for `\hyperref`s?

As per request, a minimal example:

```
\begin{theorem}
Each \hyperref[def:bounded_sequence]{bounded sequence} in $\mathbb{R}^n$
has a convergent subsequence.
\end{theorem}
```

Here, "bounded sequence" with the usual theorem style, but I would like to appear without it.

Comment: Can you make an example of what you mean?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set the corresponding `\hyperref` entry with the font declaration `\upshape`:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{hyperref,amsfonts}

\newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}

\begin{document}

\begin{theorem}\label{def:bounded_sequence}
Some bounded sequence theorem.
\end{theorem}

\begin{theorem}
Each \hyperref[def:bounded_sequence]{\upshape bounded sequence} in $\mathbb{R}^n$
has a convergent subsequence.
\end{theorem}

\end{document}
```

For a global setup you could add

```
\usepackage{letltxmacro}
\LetLtxMacro\oldhyperref\hyperref
\renewcommand{\hyperref}[2][]{\oldhyperref[#1]{\upshape #2}}
```

to your preamble.

Instead of `\upshape`, you could use other declarations like `\normalfont`.

Comment: Redefining `\hyperref` that way is not a good idea.

Answer (score 3):

The mandatory argument to `\hyperref` is actually managed by the auxiliary macro `\label@@hyperref` and it would be wrong to redefine `\hyperref`, because this disrupts all the setup the command must do for neutralizing special characters in link references.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\usepackage{hyperref} % last one

\makeatletter
\patchcmd{\label@@hyperref}{\begingroup#3}{\begingroup\upshape#3}{}{}
\patchcmd{\label@@hyperref}{{#3}}{{\textup{#3}}}{}{}
\makeatother

\newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}

\begin{document}

\begin{theorem}\label{def:bounded_sequence}
Some bounded sequence theorem.
\end{theorem}

\begin{theorem}                
Each \hyperref[def:bounded_sequence]{bounded sequence} in $\mathbb{R}^n$
has a convergent subsequence.
\end{theorem}

\end{document}
```

[image]